# DocuSign API - templates from different user accounts

Tags: docusignapi

Short version: Does the DocuSign API have the ability to send different templates from different user accounts?

Long version: We have a web form that gathers information - chooses the template id and pre-fills info into a form and then sends it along to signers.  Right now our programmer coded a procedure that sends all templates out of one user account so all docs are listed in one account.  We want to change that so different templates originate from different user accounts which can be easily determined at the template creation point.

Is this possible? If so, what is the API call or specs to make this happen? Is there anything on the account side that needs to change?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there's a solution for this, but first let me clarify.  You can only send from a template that's in your account.. you can not access templates from other accounts.

With that said, all of you have to do is copy or migrate the templates into the account that you want to send from.  There's two general methods of doing this:

1. Manually download the templates from the first account then re-upload into the second account using the DocuSign website.
2. Programmatically download the templates from account A then create (or `POST`) the templates up into the second account.

Obviously you'll need valid user credentials from each account to be able to access the templates and upload, and I believe only users with **Admin** privileges can do this.

For #1 here's a guide that explains how to download/upload templates through the DocuSign UI:  https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-download-template

For #2 see the [Templates: get](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/Templates/get/) call to retrieve a single template, see [Templates: list](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/Templates/list/) to list all account templates, and see [Templates: create](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/Templates/create/) to upload (or create) a new one in a given account.

Comment: I understand that you can move templates between accounts either manually or programatically which is very much appreciated, but my question was more directed to can you program for certain templates to come out of different user accounts automatically.  Currently, our program has all templates being sent from a single account and may be coincidentally located in the same account.  The question is what code allows you to send certain templates from certain accounts - unless what you are saying is this is not necessary and DS will send it from whatever user account the template is stored?